# Issue with Displaying error message when the file is empty

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization

I want display error message with red color when the file is empty for the first time 
but my probleme is in this method ois.available() it return 0 always and the file is not empty

### Information :

### The class of Person :

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Person implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1378867624677931843L;
    public long idPersonne;
    public String FristName ;
    public String LastName ;
    public String Adresse;

    public Personne()
    {
        idPersonne ++;
    }
    String str1 = "";
    public String toString()
    {
            str1 += "Frist Name : "+FristName +"\n";


        return str1;
    }
}
```

### The class of  Room and main test :

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Room {


    public  ArrayList<Person> Lpersonne= new ArrayList<Person>();
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    public Room()
    {

    }

    public String toString() 
    {

    String str="**********************  Display    **************************** \n";
     try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                 new BufferedInputStream(
                         new FileInputStream(
                                 new File("Person.txt"))));

if(ois.available()==0)
{
    System.err.println("File is empty");

}
else
{
        while(true)
        {
            str  +=(((Person)ois.readObject()).toString());
        }


}
     }catch (EOFException ex1) {



     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    return str;
    }

    public void addPerson(Person p1) throws EOFException
    {
         Personne P2=null;
         String str="";
          Lpersonne.add(p1); 
          try{
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                        new BufferedOutputStream(
                                new FileOutputStream(
                                        new File("Person.txt"))));

                for(Person P: Lpersonne){
                    oos.writeObject(P);
                }
                oos.close();



            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws EOFException {

Room r = new Room();
System.out.println(r);
       Person p1 = new Person();
       p1.FristName = "Firstname1" ;
       p1.LastName = "LastNam1";
       p1.Adresse = "Adresse1";
       r.addPersonne(p1);
       Person p2 = new Person();
       p2.FristName = "FristName2" ;
       p2.LastName = "LastName2";
       p2.Adresse = "Adresse2";
       r.addPerson(p2);
       Person p3 = new Person();
       p3.FristName = "FristName3" ;
       p3.LastName = "LastName3";
       p3.Adresse = "Adresse3";
       r.addPerson(p3);

}

}
```

### expected result in the first execution :

File is empty  (with red color)

********************** Display   ****************************

### expected result in the second execution :

********************** Display   ****************************

First Name : Firstname1

First Name : FristName2

First Name : FristName3

### obtained Result in the first execution : => OK

File is empty

********************** Display   ****************************

### obtained Result in the second execution : => KO

File is empty

********************** Display   ****************************

### EDIT

and when i have changed available() method and pulling out that File object and calling  file.length() == 0 like that :

```
public String toString() 
    {

    String str="**********************  Display    **************************** \n";
     try {
         File f = new File("Person.txt");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                 new BufferedInputStream(
                         new FileInputStream(
                                f)));
    //  System.out.println(ois.available());

        if(f.length()==0)
        {
            System.err.println("File is empty");

        }
        else
        {
        while(true)
        {
            str  +=(((Personne)ois.readObject()).toString());
        }


        }
     }catch (EOFException ex1) {



     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    return str;
    }
```

it returns

### obtained Result in the first execution : => KO

********************** Display   ****************************

### obtained Result in the second execution : => OK

********************** Display   ****************************

Nom : Firstname1

Nom : FristName2

Nom : FristName3

Comment: I am a little confused. You said it *always* returns 0, so that means it should always print out "File is empty". However, your actual results do not show this at all. So that seems like it *never* returns 0. Is that true?

Comment: when i has displayed   ois.available() like that System.out.Println(ois.available() ) its always return 0 so always i have   ********************** Display ****************************

Comment: and that's true what you have said the obtained result is without this condition if(ois.available()==0)
{
    System.err.println("File is empty");

}

Comment: its just for showing what i want do ( the algorithm )

Comment: its getting zéro i don't know why and my file is not empty

Comment: i have edited my subject question always i have file is empty  ********************** Display ****************************

Comment: Instead of using the `available()` method, what about pulling out that `File` object and call `boolean isEmpty = file.length()  == 0`

Comment: i have already tried and the same probleme :(

Comment: I haven't the same probleme in this case i have this result the first execution i have only Display without file is empty and the second execution is ok ;) ... but me i want display the error message in the first execution not only *****Display*****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Room**, change your `toString()` to this:

```
public String toString() {
    String str = "**********************  Display    **************************** \n";
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;

    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Person.txt"));

        while (true) {
            try {
                str += (((Person) ois.readObject()).toString());
            } catch (EOFException ex1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (EOFException ex1) {
        System.err.println("File is empty\n");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }finally {
        if (ois != null) {
            try {
                ois.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error closing ois");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Just as a side note, I changed the way you declared the `oos` in the method `addPerson` to this as well (to clean it up some):

```
public void addPerson(Person p1) throws EOFException {
    Lpersonne.add(p1);

    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Person.txt");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

        for (Person P : Lpersonne) {
            oos.writeObject(P);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (oos != null) {
            try {
                oos.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error closing out oos");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so mush !! all is fine now

Comment: Excellent! I changed some code too so that it closes the streams. And an upvote is always welcomed ;-)

Comment: Glad I could figure it out for you